# Ошибка при повторном добавлении строки в TableView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Здравствуйте. У меня есть TableView, в который я добавляю информацию по нажатию клавиши.

Если записать что-то в array по коду снизу, выйти из ВьюКонтроллера и снова зайти, то при повторном добавлении через [ ***addObject:***], краш программы. 
Лог:

> ‘NSInternalInconsistencyException’,
> reason: ’-[__NSCFArray
> insertObject:atIndex:]:

Код добавления:

```
NSMutableArray *fruits;

NSUserDefaults *load = [NSUserDefaults stadartUserDefaults];
fruits = [load objectForKey:@"TableLoad"]; // выгружаем сохранение

if (fruits == NULL) // если сохранения не было, и fruits обнулился
{
fruits = [NSMitableArray array];
}

[fruits addObject:@"Неважно"]; // Добавление объекта

[load setObject:fruits forKey:@"TableLoad"]; // Сохраняем обратно
[load synchrinize];
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь изменить неизменяемый массив.
Вот решение вашей проблемы:

```
fruits = [[load objectForKey:@"TableLoad"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Действительно... Спасибо)